# Seeking images of Devenish brewery labels

Tags: breweries

I’m looking for information about Devenish brewery. I found a few images of beer labels that I love and am doing a little art project to recreate the whole set.
If you have any information, access to images or maybe even Devenish labels in your possession I’d love to see and hear all about it!

Comment: You are unlikely to get much here. A google image search has a lot of hits. https://www.google.com/search?q=Devenish%20brewery%20label&tbm=isch

Comment: In [**this article**](http://breweryhistory.com/wiki/index.php?title=Devenish_%26_Co._Ltd) you may find some  info :)

Comment: @EricS serious?

Comment: @MattAllegro this is a great wiki! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Came across this, am i barking up the right tree?